# Setting a requirement of PHP 5.4 or higher

Tags: php, php-5.4, php-5.5, php-5.6

I need to require at least PHP 5.4 in my app.

The current code detects only 5.0 or higher:

```
$phpv=phpversion();
$t=explode(".", $phpv);
if($t[0]>=5)
    $ok=1;
else
    $ok=0;
```

Typing 5.4 or 54 instead of 5 does not work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the second part of the explode :

```
if($t[0]>=5 && $t[1]>=4)
...
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`version_compare`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php):

```
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0') < 0) {
    echo 'Minimum required version is 5.4.0. You have: ' . PHP_VERSION . "\n";
}
```